# Does John Pain get cards drawn at the beginning of a player's turn or from Stage Coach and Wells Fargo?

Tags: bang

The "Wild West Show" character John Pain states:

`If [John] has less than 6 cards in hand, each time any player "draws!", John adds the card just drawn to his hand.`

I've always interpreted this as only applying to cards like Barrel, Jail and Dynamite or character attributes like Jourdonnais but not to the two cards drawn at the beginning of a player's turn or cards like Stage Coach and Wells Fargo.  Recently I was playing with someone and the question came up and I couldn't find anything in the rules about it other than the distinct use of the term `"draw!"` in certain instances.

Does John Pain get cards drawn at the beginning of a player's turn and from Stage Coach and Wells Fargo or just from cards like Barrel, Jail and Dynamite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in this case draw! refers to flipping a card and checking the suit revealed for something to fire like barrel or dynamite. Players drawing cards for their turn, stagecoach/wells fargo/dodge/bible or any other ability that adds a card to hand does not count.

Here is a guide that gives some more information on the draw! ability.

http://bangcardgame.blogspot.com/2011/09/character-guide-john-pain.html